# How to show error Message in the login page when using JAAS instead of redirection to error page

Tags: java, security, jboss, jaas

i successfully secured my web application using JAAS
to do that i followed the tutorial on this page 
http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/09/18/configure-jaas-jboss-7-1-mysql/
but the problem is that you need to define a specific page to handle the case when the user entered an invalid username/password "error.jsp"

I want to show the user a neat error message on the login page instead of having him clicking on some link or press back to navigate to the login page again .
can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tweak available which we used in a similar scenario.

e.g. let us say the URL of your page is www.servername.com/login.html

We provided the error page URL as www.servername.com/login.html?error=true

We kept the url of error page same as that of login page, and passed a parameter in URL as error.

In the login page, we checked if this parameter was true, we showed the error message.

Later, we used the same parameter to show different kinds of error messages.

Comment: interesting way  ,anyway i endedup using Shiro to do the security instead of using JAAS, shiro is much easier and it doesn't require any changes to the server XMLs. plug and play. thanks for your answer though.